# How to navigate inside right menu in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sidebar

I am using [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) for my IOS application

my issue is i have to change right side menu controller when clicking right side menu item. that means i need to navigate inside right sidebar & right sidebar should be open. also center view controller should be same as before. how can i do this?

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words. :)

Comment: what you tried?. you have done any code for it